# Attempting to convert jQuery mouseover to an on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code currently only loads during mouse over and mouse out events. I would like it to instead execute on page load. I've tried modifying the event to read... but then it just stops functioning all together. Any suggestion? Also, any suggestions on how to add checkbox to disable the functionality?

```
$(function() {


  $(".sparkley:last").sparkleh({
    color: "rainbow",
    count: 50,
    overlap: 5

  });

});


$.fn.sparkleh = function( options ) {

  return this.each( function(k,v) {

    var $this = $(v).css("position","relative");

    var settings = $.extend({
      width: $this.outerWidth(),
      height: $this.outerHeight(),
      color: "#FFFFFF",
      count: 30,
      overlap: 0,
      speed: 1
    }, options );

    var sparkle = new Sparkle( $this, settings );

    $this.on({
      "mouseover focus" : function(e) {
        sparkle.over();
      },
      "mouseout blur" : function(e) {
        sparkle.out();
      }
    });

  });

}


function Sparkle( $parent, options ) {
  this.options = options;
  this.init( $parent );
}

Sparkle.prototype = {

  "init" : function( $parent ) {

    var _this = this;

    this.$canvas = 
      $("<canvas>")
        .addClass("sparkle-canvas")
        .css({
          position: "absolute",
          top: "-"+_this.options.overlap+"px",
          left: "-"+_this.options.overlap+"px",
          "pointer-events": "none"
         })
        .appendTo($parent);

    this.canvas = this.$canvas[0];
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");

    this.sprite = new Image();
    this.sprites = [0,6,13,20];
    this.sprite.src = this.datauri;

    this.canvas.width = this.options.width + ( this.options.overlap * 2);
    this.canvas.height = this.options.height + ( this.options.overlap * 2);


    this.particles = this.createSparkles( this.canvas.width , this.canvas.height );

    this.anim = null;
    this.fade = false;

  },

  "createSparkles" : function( w , h ) {

    var holder = [];

    for( var i = 0; i < this.options.count; i++ ) {

      var color = this.options.color;

      if( this.options.color == "rainbow" ) {
        color = '#'+ ('000000' + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16)).slice(-6);
      } else if( $.type(this.options.color) === "array" ) {
        color = this.options.color[ Math.floor(Math.random()*this.options.color.length) ];
      }

      holder[i] = {
        position: {
          x: Math.floor(Math.random()*w),
          y: Math.floor(Math.random()*h)
        },
        style: this.sprites[ Math.floor(Math.random()*4) ],
        delta: {
          x: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) - 500,
          y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) - 500
        },
        size: parseFloat((Math.random()*2).toFixed(2)),
        color: color
      };

    }

    return holder;

  },

  "draw" : function( time, fade ) {

    var ctx = this.context;

    ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height );

    for( var i = 0; i < this.options.count; i++ ) {

      var derpicle = this.particles[i];
      var modulus = Math.floor(Math.random()*7);

      if( Math.floor(time) % modulus === 0 ) {
        derpicle.style = this.sprites[ Math.floor(Math.random()*4) ];
     }

      ctx.save();
      ctx.globalAlpha = derpicle.opacity;
      ctx.drawImage(this.sprite, derpicle.style, 0, 7, 7, derpicle.position.x, derpicle.position.y, 7, 7);

      if( this.options.color ) {  

        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-atop";
        ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
        ctx.fillStyle = derpicle.color;
        ctx.fillRect(derpicle.position.x, derpicle.position.y, 7, 7);

      }

       ctx.restore();

    }


  },

  "update" : function() {

     var _this = this;

     this.anim = window.requestAnimationFrame( function(time) {

       for( var i = 0; i < _this.options.count; i++ ) {

         var u = _this.particles[i];

         var randX = ( Math.random() > Math.random()*2 );
         var randY = ( Math.random() > Math.random()*3 );

         if( randX ) {
           u.position.x += ((u.delta.x * _this.options.speed) / 1500); 
         }        

         if( !randY ) {
           u.position.y -= ((u.delta.y * _this.options.speed) / 800);
         }

         if( u.position.x > _this.canvas.width ) {
           u.position.x = -7;
         } else if ( u.position.x < -7 ) {
           u.position.x = _this.canvas.width; 
         }

         if( u.position.y > _this.canvas.height ) {
           u.position.y = -7;
           u.position.x = Math.floor(Math.random()*_this.canvas.width);
         } else if ( u.position.y < -7 ) {
           u.position.y = _this.canvas.height; 
           u.position.x = Math.floor(Math.random()*_this.canvas.width);
         }

         if( _this.fade ) {
           u.opacity -= 0.02;
         } else {
            u.opacity -= 0.005;
         }

         if( u.opacity <= 0 ) {
           u.opacity = ( _this.fade ) ? 0 : 1;
          }

       }

       _this.draw( time );

       if( _this.fade ) {
         _this.fadeCount -= 1;
         if( _this.fadeCount < 0 ) {
            window.cancelAnimationFrame( _this.anim );
          } else {
            _this.update(); 
          }
       } else {
         _this.update();
       }

     });

  },

  "cancel" : function() {

    this.fadeCount = 100;

  },

  "over" : function() {

    window.cancelAnimationFrame( this.anim );

    for( var i = 0; i < this.options.count; i++ ) {
      this.particles[i].opacity = Math.random();
    }

    this.fade = false;
    this.update();

   },

  "out" : function() {

    this.fade = true;
    this.cancel();

  },



  "datauri" :     "data:image/png;base64,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"

};


 $.fn.imagesLoaded = function(callback){
  var elems = this.filter('img'),
       len   = elems.length,
      blank = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw==";

  elems.bind('load.imgloaded',function(){
      if (--len <= 0 && this.src !== blank){ 
        elems.unbind('load.imgloaded');
        callback.call(elems,this); 
      }
  }).each(function(){
     // cached images don't fire load sometimes, so we reset src.
      if (this.complete || this.complete === undefined){
        var src = this.src;
        // webkit hack from https://groups.google.com/group/jquery-dev/browse_thread/thread/eee6ab7b2da50e1f
    // data uri bypasses webkit log warning (thx doug jones)
    this.src = blank;
    this.src = src;
 }  
  }); 

  return this;
};
```

Comment: create a snippet this does not help anyone , and show what you have done so far to achieve it

Comment: Hi, please hover over 'Hello'
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rvKKom

Answer (score 0):

used the following:

```
jQuery(window).on("load", function(){
  sparkle.over();
});
```